# How do I use LINQ to compare a date and a datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to seed a database with two lists.  The first list is just a bunch of items.  The second list is a bunch of junk that references the first list.  I'm trying to reference items from first list in the second list of junk, via LINQ, but I'm fairly certain I'm not doing it right:

For example, List 1:

```
var items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item { ItemtId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 05, 12, 30, 30), Text = "Cheese" },
    new Item { ItemtId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 05, 12, 30, 30), Text = "Lettuce" },
    new Item { ItemtId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 05, 12, 30, 30), Text = "Ground Beef" },
    new Item { ItemtId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 03, 12, 30, 30), Text = "Ketchup" },
    new Item { ItemtId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 03, 12, 30, 30), Text = "Mustard" },
};

var junk= new List<Junk>()
{
    new Junk { JunkId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 05, 10, 00, 00), Items = items.Where(d => d.DateTime.ToShortDateString() == new DateTime(2014, 09, 05).ToShortDateString()},
    new Junk { JunkId = 2, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 03, 11, 00, 00), Items = items.Where(d => d.DateTime.ToShortDateString() == new DateTime(2014, 09, 03).ToShortDateString()}
};
```

This seems like it should be the answer to me, because I'm only interested in the date and not the time, but it doesn't seed like this.  I get the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression.

Any thoughts on how to build a better solution?

**UPDATE**

Looks like I didn't transcribe my code accurately to the site, and ended up finding my problem.

In my original code, I had:

```
new Junk { JunkId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 05, 10, 00, 00), Items = context.Items.Where(d => d.DateTime.Date == new DateTime(2014, 09, 05) }
```

When I should have had

```
new Junk { JunkId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 05, 10, 00, 00), Items = items.Where(d => d.DateTime.Date == new DateTime(2014, 09, 05) }
```

I'd been flirting with .ToShortDateString() unnecessarily

Comment: It looks like you missed ')' after `.ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change filter to:

```
.Where(d => d.DateTime.Date == new DateTime(2014, 09, 05))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TruncateTime` function of `EntityFunctions` Class.

```
new Junk { JunkId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 05, 10, 00, 00), Items = items.Where(d => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateTime) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(new DateTime(2014, 09, 05))}
```

**Note:** If you using EntityFramework 6 then it should be System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(...) method from EntityFramework.dll.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery (the Items = part of the Junk variable) isn't a list but an enumerable, so it doesn't get materialized untill it's enumerated, and it's not enumerated untill you use it, down the road, in your linq to entities query.

If you change it as such :

```
var junk= new List<Junk>()
{
    new Junk { JunkId = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 05, 10, 00, 00), Items = items.Where(d => d.DateTime.ToShortDateString() == new DateTime(2014, 09, 05).ToShortDateString()).ToList()},   // this one will work as it gets materialized right now, not later, so by the time you pass it to linq to entities later it will already be a simple list of diferences, it won't try to compute "toshortdatestring" later, that will already be done
    new Junk { JunkId = 2, DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 09, 03, 11, 00, 00), Items = items.Where(d => d.DateTime.ToShortDateString() == new DateTime(2014, 09, 03).ToShortDateString()}
};
```

Comment: Good point.  I'll need to move that part outside of this part.